# jQuery unable to remove list elements

Tags: jquery, list

I have a tree with `ul` and has the following structure:

```
<div id="Tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="collapseLink" href="#">
        <span class="hide">Expand Root Node</span>
      </a>
      <a class="selectLink" href="#">
        Root Node
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li id="item_1">Sub Node 1</li>
        <li id="item_2">Sub Node 2</li>
        <li id="item_3">Sub Node 3</li>
        <li id="item_4">Sub Node 4</li>
        <li id="item_5">Sub Node 5</li>
        <li id="item_6">Sub Node 6</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I would ideally like to limit the number of the Sub Nodes in the tree and tried to implement that with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var rootNode = $('#Tree ul li a:first');
    // If the root node has an 'expandLink' class then it's closed and can be opened    //(via a click)
    if (rootNode.hasClass('expandLink')){
       rootNode.click();
       limitRootNodes();
    }
    function limitRootNodes() {
        // Get the direct child nodes for the root list element
        var tree_ul = $('#Tree ul li ul:first').children();
        // list limit
        var max_listCount = 3;
        // remove the last element if the list size exceeds the limit
        while (tree_ul.size() > max_listCount){
            $('li:last-child', tree_ul).remove();  
        }   
    }
});
```

However, the above code is not removing the excess list elements. Any suggestions as to what is causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another way to approach this. Replace your while-loop with this:

```
tree_ul.each(function(n,item){
   if(n > (max_listCount - 1))
     $(item).remove();
});
```

**EDIT:** Also, in your HTML example, the first anchor tag has class `collapseLink`, but this code is looking for the class `expandLink` before calling the `limitRootNodes()` function, so it is not going to get called.

```
if (rootNode.hasClass('expandLink')){
   rootNode.click();
   limitRootNodes();
}
```

Comment: Spot on José, after refactoring the code according to T B's, John's and your suggestions, my app is now working! Kudos for the decisive help.

Answer (score 4):

Your `tree_ul` variable is selecting all the children of that `ul`, then you're trying to select `:last-child` of the children of that `li` (for which no children exist). Try:

```
$('li:last', tree_ul).remove();
```

From the jQuery Documentation:

> **:last-child**
>
> Matches all elements that are the last
>   child of their parent. While :last
>   matches only a single element, this
>   matches more then one: One for each
>   parent.
>
> **:last**
>
> Matches the last selected element.

Another option is to use [`filter()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/filter):

```
var max_listCount = 3;
$('#Tree ul li ul:first').children().filter(function(index){ 
  return (index >= max_listCount); 
}).remove();
```

This will remove all child nodes with `index >= max_listCount`.

Comment: Thanks John for your timely contribution. However, on changing the attribute as per advice it didn't work. I would like to believe maybe where I'm calling the method is wrong?

Comment: T B has pointed out my mistake. I've update it to include the filter() function which is probably the cleanest way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

First off, as John has already pointed out, you are not going to remove anything with the selector that you are using.  I removed the "children()" part of the tree_ul variable to help with that.  Also, since you are storing tree_ul in a variable, tree_ul.size() will return the same value even after you remove children since it will not be updated after items are removed.

Here is the updated code that should work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var rootNode = $('#Tree ul li a:first');

// If the root node has an 'expandLink' class then it's closed and can be opened    //(via a click)
if (rootNode.hasClass('expandLink')){
   rootNode.click();
   limitRootNodes();
}
function limitRootNodes() {
    // list limit
    var max_listCount = 3;
    // remove the last element if the list size exceeds the limit
    $('#Tree ul li ul:first').children().filter(function(index){ 
        return (index >= max_listCount); 
    }).remove();

}
});
```

Here is a link to view it in action http://jsbin.com/ovala

**EDIT: I updated to include John's filter() solution.**

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! App now works, many thanks T B and same goes to you John.